# How to get every nth column in pandas with an specific last nth column?

Tags: python, slice

Using the function `row[3::2]` will return the row from every 2nd column starting from the 3rd column.

But how can you adjust it so it returns up to a certain column? That is, how can you adjust it so it only gets every 2nd column up to the nth column.

Comment: To go from `3` to `n` taking every other item would be `row[3:n:2]`.  To take `n` items starting at `3` and taking every other would be something more like `row[3::2][:n]`.  In that case it would probably make more sense to use something like `itertools.islice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing syntax is `start: stop: step`, so to return only up to a certain column you can use:

```
row[3:10:2]
```

It's also possible to chain indexers like this:

```
row[3:10][::2]
```